# iOS 5 - How do you combine different types of view in one window?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

For instance, say I wanted to load a view that had a table view controller, but only on the bottom half of the view. The top half might contain labels or buttons, etc. I am aware that there is a "SplitViewController" Class for the iPad, but how do you implement this on the iPhone? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On iOS4, you can put labels, buttons of the top half onto a topView(UIView), place the bottomView(UITableView) under it. 
On iOS5, childViewController is supported, so you can also put them into two different UIViewControllers.